# Creating agenda view with PHP MySQL - Divide fetched MySQL rows by year and month

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

Good afternoon everyone.

I've got a MySQL table organized like this:

```
| ID | Date       | Some_Information           |
+----+------------+----------------------------+
|  1 | 2016-03-02 | A note about this day...   |
|  2 | 2016-03-22 | A note about that day...   |
|  3 | 2016-04-05 | Another note...            |
```

I need to display this data in a similiar way to [Google Calendar app's agenda view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43S0H.jpg). To do this I should:

1. Divide fetched rows, already ordered by date, by month;
2. Before displaying data corresponding to each month (let's say march), display a `<div>` with some heading for the corresponding month.

Can someone please tell me if this is possible, and how?

Comment: First, store dates using a date data type.

Comment: Have any code you tried?

Comment: @Strawberry, _of course_ i stored dates using the proper data type. The example above is for illustration purposes.

Comment: @Shank : actually, I'm trying to find out how I can make this happen. Until now, I only figured out how to fetch data for last 3 months, using this command: 'select * from table where date >= now() - interval 3 month'

Comment: Anyone sufficiently well versed in SQL to answer this question, is quite capable of understanding properly formatted dates. Please fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some research. I solved this in a simple way.

I used this query to fetch result for the last month, mixing it with an incremental variable, named `$offset`, and putting it in a for cycle:

```
$offset = 1;
$sub_offset = $offset - 1;
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (date >= last_day(now()) + interval 1 day - interval ".$offset." month and date <= last_day(now()) + interval 1 day - interval ".$sub_offset." month) ORDER BY date DESC";
```

At the beginning of the `for` cycle, I declare once `$offset`, echo the month heading, execute the query and display its results via `while` and `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`. Then I increment the `$offset` variable, and the `for` cycle repeats itself, just until I want it to display months.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:

```
SELECT
    table.ID,
    table.date,
    table.Some_Information,
    MONTH(table.date) AS m,
    YEAR(table.date) AS y
FROM table
ORDER BY table.date DESC
```

PHP:

```
$lastYm = '';
foreach($result as $row) {
    $ym = $row['y'] . '-' . $row['m'];
    if($ym != $lastYm) {
        echo '<div class="month">' . $row['m'] . '</div>';
        $lastYm = $ym;
    }
    echo '<div class="info">' . $row['Some_Information'] . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your version, but I found tricky to work with this code for what I wanted to achieve.